# Why is there a Moore's Law for atomic clocks?

Tags: time, metrology

From the [NIST website](https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/primary-standard-nist-f1):
[image]

If you add the more recent data points, like [this one](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41566-019-0493-4) in 2019, which achieved $~10^{-17}$ fractional instability, the trendline continues.

Why should there be a Moore's law for clocks? And are there fundamental limits to clock uncertainty?

Comment: Moore's law isn't a law of nature. It's a target that the different companies in the semiconductor manufacturing equipment industry have worked together to achieve. I suspect what you're seeing for atomic clocks is (somewhat) similar. The accuracy improves as researchers around the world put more effort into improving it.

Comment: @ThePhoton I think Moore's law is not just artificial, but is partially a scaling law, like Zipf's law. Still, even if it's just artificial, why a straight line instead of a more curvy one? And the other question is: what would end this exponential improvement? The end of atomic clock Moore's law?

Comment: The thing with Moore's Law is, if you're currently (for example) working at the 45 nm node. And you are working for the wafer inspection company. It doesn't do you any good to develop technology for the 9 nm node, if the lithography company, the mask writing company, etc., all develop for the 28 nm node. You've got an ahead-of-its-time product that nobody will want to buy. So all these companies have to agree to work to the same goals each year, and Moore's law guides those goals.

Comment: For the atomic clock it's not quite the same because maybe not so many companies are involved and not so much money is on the line. But just reading the abstract you linked to, they mention a new class of lasers based on a new reference cavity technology. The researchers developing those things had to do their work before the atomic clock researcher could combine them with other stuff to hit a new milestone for the atomic clock.

Comment: That would seem like a Moore's law indeed, in the sense of a technological improvement that follows an exponential curve over time. I do believe there is a natural law behind it, because every improvement we make in technology has a potential impact on other technologies. Computers help making better computers, for example. So I disagree with The Photon saying this is just a guideline for the industry. It is an observation first.